# How do I get a tikz picture and text to align in a certain way?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, alignment

So I want to have text next to a graph, and my solution was creating a two celled table.

```
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ c p{100pt} }
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[thin,gray!40] (0,0) grid (4,4);
            \draw[->](0,0)--(4,0) node[right]{$x$};
            \draw[->](0,0)--(0,4) node[above]{$y$};
            \draw[line  width=2pt ,red,-stealth](1,0)--(1,4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    &  Blah blah blah blah $\boldsymbol{u}$.   \\
```

And when it comes out, the text lines up with the bottom of the picture, is there a way which I can "trick" the text into thinking that it should line up with the top of the picture.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a complete compilable code?

Comment: You can always set the baseline of the tizkpicture to something. Give e.g. the `$y$` node a name and align it to it.     `\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(y.base)]
        \draw[thin,gray!40] (0,0) grid (4,4);
            \draw[->](0,0)--(4,0) node[right]{$x$};
            \draw[->](0,0)--(0,4) node[above](y){$y$};
            \draw[line  width=2pt ,red,-stealth](1,0)--(1,4);
    \end{tikzpicture}`

Answer (score 2):

Just spelling out my comment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ c p{100pt} }
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(y.base)]
        \draw[thin,gray!40] (0,0) grid (4,4);
            \draw[->](0,0)--(4,0) node[right]{$x$};
            \draw[->](0,0)--(0,4) node[above](y){$y$};
            \draw[line  width=2pt ,red,-stealth](1,0)--(1,4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    &  Blah blah blah blah $\boldsymbol{u}$.   \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And yes, I also know one should not use the `center` environment, but I have no idea how the full document looks like so I kept it.

Comment: I'll be happy to remove my answer in favor of someone who also explains why one should not use center and so on. Of course, I am aware of the fact that one can use arbitrary shifts e.g. by saying `[baseline=([yshift=-5pt]y.base)]`, or one could use minipages and so on.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to side by side minipages or tabular, you can use a `tcolorbox` with options `sidebyside` (places upper and lower boxes side by side) and `empty` (no tcolorbox is drawn). You decide the vertical alignment between parts with `sidebyside align` (center by default).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[sidebyside, empty]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(y.base)]
        \draw[thin,gray!40] (0,0) grid (4,4);
            \draw[->](0,0)--(4,0) node[right]{$x$};
            \draw[->](0,0)--(0,4) node[above](y){$y$};
            \draw[line  width=2pt ,red,-stealth](1,0)--(1,4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\tcblower
Blah blah blah blah $\boldsymbol{u}$.  
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[sidebyside, empty, sidebyside align=top]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(y.base)]
        \draw[thin,gray!40] (0,0) grid (4,4);
            \draw[->](0,0)--(4,0) node[right]{$x$};
            \draw[->](0,0)--(0,4) node[above](y){$y$};
            \draw[line  width=2pt ,red,-stealth](1,0)--(1,4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\tcblower
Blah blah blah blah $\boldsymbol{u}$.  
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]